# Was kissing punishable by death in 16th century Naples?

Tags: history, law

According to [Dr Karl](http://www.abc.net.au/science/articles/2003/08/28/923750.htm?site=science/greatmomentsinscience):

> And in 16th century Naples, in Italy,
>   kissing was an offence that carried
>   the death penalty.

Is that true?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

That exact phrase is repeated numerous times on what appears to be thousands of web sites.  However, in the 50 that I took a look at, none of them sourced it.  The best I have found is reference to a law passed on March 9th, 1562.  Apparently an anti-obscenity law.  As to how strictly it was enforced, I again am only getting references to the law itself (without any actual text of the law).

Given this pattern, I would suspect that perhaps an anti-obscenity law was passed on that date in Naples, but it was not strictly aimed at kissing, but other behaviour deemed immoral by the local magistrates/clergy/rulers.  Kissing was just one thing mentioned.

I will continue to search for the original text of this law, but History is not my greatest subject, so I am leaving this as a wiki for the community.

Comment: Absence of evidence is evidence of absence.

Comment: I've found this on many Italian websites too but none of them has a source either.

Comment: An anti-obscenity law would seem to suggest that the crime was "kissing in public", rather than just kissing. Is that fair?

Comment: @Oddthinking A 1992 book says "1562 In Naples, kissing in public is made punishable by death" https://books.google.com/books?id=SYGQgwHTuE0C&q=kissing++Naples++1562&dq=kissing++Naples++1562&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi0rPy50crSAhVj7IMKHQZDCbUQ6AEIKzAD

Answer (score 0):

The book [The Kiss and Its History](https://books.google.com/books?id=UQgNAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA61&dq=Holberg%20kiss%20naples&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiXxfT808rSAhWC14MKHb44BocQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=Holberg%20kiss%20naples&f=false), translated into English in 1901, says:

> The question of kissing by main force can be treated not only from an ethical, but also from a juristic point of view.  [Holberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ludvig_Holberg) relates that in Naples the individual who kissed in the street a woman against her will was punished by not being allowed to approach within thirty miles distance of the spot where the outrage had taken place